# Can anyone identify this spinner with 1-5 and a skull?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

My son has just inherited a large box of Lego, we're hoping someone can help identify what set this might be from.

Answer (score 8):

It's the center of set [2519 Skeleton Bowling](http://brickset.com/sets/2519-1/Skeleton-Bowling):

[image]